# Moderate five star ratings given by users

Tags: 7, rating

I want to create an admin interface to moderate the ratings given by site users.

I am using fivestar (d7) module for rating users.

I tried with creating views with editable rating fields, but its not giving the expected results.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Fivestar rating works fine with views.What do you mean by 'not giving the expected results'?

Comment: Sorry. I mean I am not able to change the average rating with the editable rating fields

Comment: What's the use case for this? Changing the fivestar ratings manually somehow strikes me as defeating its purpose... If you want to present the site administrators' ratings as a user average, you might as well have a separate field for that, and only let the administrators edit it.

Comment: @olyN! Yes, got it. I'll use separate field instead of changing 'fivestar' module. Thanks for redirecting me